# Using KVC for setting inaccessible properties. Is this allowed?

Tags: ios, swift

Using KVC for setting inaccessible properties. Is this advised ?

Say I want to change `UIDatePicker` text color which is not allowed by Apple framework.

Can I edit the properties using KVC?

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKey: "textColor")
```

Is this a good programming practice? Because we are accessing private properties using KVC

Answer (score 1):

By inaccessible, I assume you mean "private API".

There are two problems with this approach:

1. Apple will reject your app if you submit it to the store; the main reason being that:
2. Private APIs are private precisely so that developers don't rely on them: typically the API is still a work in progress inside Apple and therefore the spec might change at any future release of the OS. Apple can use the private APIs because -of course- they get a chance to update all their pre-installed apps every time the OS is updated. But third any party apps relying on them will likely break.

If you are planning to release your app in-house, B2B, Enterprise, jailbreak, etc. you don't have to worry about rejection; however, the likelyhood of your app breaking when (say) your users upgrade from iOS 9 to iOS 10 is still there.

**EDIT:** After thinking about it, I'm not sure if Apple can detect your KVC access of private properties; after all, you are not calling any private method (getters/setters included). But I don't know how they "scan" the apps they review, so...

Answer (score 0):

Is this a good programming practice?

No.

Why?

It violates the basics of oop. An object is offering a set of methods and properties you can rely on. Behind it you can't know if the object will have that property inside. The object could be something completely different that just implements the methods that are available.